# Can I have different classes (using flavors) in a library module for different application modules?

Tags: android, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

I have two applications: **Application Module A** and **Application Module B**. They both use **Library Module X**.

Inside **Library Module X** I have some different behaviors depending of which app is using the library. I thougth about three alternatives to anchieve that.

**1º** Hardcoded mentioning the applications. *someClass* would be injected by the application or just check the package. (The worst one I think):

```
if (someClass.isApplicationA()) {
   doThis()
} else {
   doThat()
}
```

**2º** Hardcoded mentioning what is about to be done. *someClass* would be injected by the application. (I don't like it to much either):

```
if (someClass.shouldDoThis()) {
   doThis()
} else {
   doThat()
}
```

3º Using flavors. I would define a flavor *A* for **Application Module A** and a flavor *B* for **Application Module B**. In **Library Module X** I would define both flavors. So I would put the custom code in some specific classes that have different versions for each flavor.

```
customClassByFlavor.justDoIt()
```

Everywhere I only see flavors been used for a single application. Is this a correct use of it?

Comment: Flavours are evil. Applications should pass changing behavior to the constructor of a library class.

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way to achieve this is

1. Ask the app to specify a identifier / key in their manifest
2. Ask the app to specify  a variable in their build.gradle file

```
     defaultConfig {
            resValue "string", "identifier", "identifierConstant"      
        }
```

Use the variable in you app, like you acesss a string constant

```
    context.getString(R.string.identifier);
```

3. Pick the package name of app from default applicationId in build.gradle file

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.example"            
    }
```